# Using awk to replace block of text in a file

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to use awk to replace a selection of lines (0,51) in a html file, however I've only figured out how to copy those lines from the original file and either append them to another file or replace the entire file, including lines below 51.

So far i have

```
awk 'NR>=0 && NR<=51' index.html > MATLAB.html
```

This replaces lines below line 51 in MATLAB.html though. Is there anyway I can keep the original file and replace only lines 0-51?

Comment: If you [edit] your question to add concise, testable sample input and expected output (obviously make the example a range of 3 or 4 lines out of 10 or less, not 51+ lines) then we can best help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I THINK what you're trying to do is this:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) && 
{ head -n 51 index.html; tail -n +52 MATLAB.html; } > "$tmp" &&
mv -- "$tmp" MATLAB.html
```

You can do that using awk instead of head+tail if you like with:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) && 
awk -v lim=51 '
    NR==FNR {
        if ( FNR <= lim ) {
            print
        }
        next
    }
    FNR > lim
' index.html MATLAB.html > "$tmp" &&
mv -- "$tmp" MATLAB.html
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great, i've tried to implement that into a for loop, however its just deleting code now, its supposed to go through each html file and update them from the index.html file. I dont supposed you could help?

`for f in $FILES;
do
 if $f = index.html
 then
 echo "here"
 else 
  echo "Updating $f file..."
  tmp=$(mktemp) && 
  { head -n 51 index.html; tail -n +52 $f; } > "$tmp" &&
  mv -- "$tmp" $f
 fi
done`

Comment: You're welcome. Ask a new followup question. We can't see formatted code or sample input/output in a comment and [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are highly discouraged.